# sonar exclude patterns seem to work not anymore

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, rules, sonarqube-scan

we want to update to sonarqube 5.6.6 and provide information via Jenkins buildjobs (sonarqube plugin 2.5) . For our paths, which contain generated sources we have added a configuration `sonar.exclusions=src/gen/**'` which worked before, but seems to have no effect with new version. I have tried to configured it in both **sonar-project.properties** and **web frontend,** no change. Can you please give me a hint if this is a bug? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Anything relevant in the analysis logs?

Comment: Hi Ann and thank you for your quick reaction. Let's get deeper in the problem... Meanwhile I noticed that in sonar the generated code, which is excluded by my exclude is not shown - This seems to be correct. But the problem is that in one project I get an timeout from findbugs. So I think the exclude has no impact on findbugs. The file .sonar/findbugs-result.xml is empty. Can you please give men example how to exclude packages in findbugs analysis with sonar? Thank you

Comment: I can't help you with FindBugs. You should [edit] your question to make it specific to FindBugs & perhaps that will draw the right kind of attention.